# How to properly clear and update a textarea element?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having difficulties clearing and then 'redrawing' a textarea element. I have a HTML doc setup like this:

The problem seems to be occurring in the updateLog function. The numbers 0-4 are printed as they should be, but once '5' is added and the array is shifted, the textarea doesn't seem to change anymore (it should display "12345" then "23456" etc.). I have so far tested and found that the function is being called every second, the array is being properly shifted and that the textarea's value is cleared before the for loop which 'draws' to the textarea. I'm completely stumped here.

```js
var logWidth = 60
var logHeight = 5
document.getElementById('log').setAttribute("rows", logHeight)
document.getElementById('log').setAttribute("cols", logWidth)


var canLogPrint = true
var txt = document.getElementById('log')
var x = 0
var logContents = []

setInterval(function() {
  if (canLogPrint) {
    updateLog(x.toString())
    x += 1
  }
}, 1000)

function updateLog(message) {
  logContents.push(message)
  if (logContents.length > logHeight) {
    logContents.shift()
  }
  txt.value = ''
  for (s in logContents) {
    txt.value += s + '\n'
  }
}

function pauseLog() {
  canLogPrint = !canLogPrint
}
```

```css
#log {
  /*resize: none;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id='log' rows=25 cols=60 autofocus readonly></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="pauseLog()">PAUSE</button>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what it is your final goal is here. Do you just want to show 5 numbers that keep shifting by one every second?

Comment: @ScottMarcus well eventually I want it to be a sort of auto-scrolling console log that acts a bit like a queue, so that when a new message is added, it will shift down by removing the oldest message, if that makes sense. I'm just using numbers at the minute until I get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var logWidth = 60
var logHeight = 5
document.getElementById('log').setAttribute("rows", logHeight)
document.getElementById('log').setAttribute("cols", logWidth)


var canLogPrint = true
var txt = document.getElementById('log')
var x = 0
var logContents = []

setInterval(function() {
  if (canLogPrint) {
    updateLog(x.toString())
    x += 1
  }

}, 1000)

function updateLog(message) {
  logContents.push(message)
  if (logContents.length > logHeight) {
    logContents.shift();
    txt.value = logContents.join('\n');
  }
  txt.value = ''
    txt.value = logContents.join('\n');
}

function pauseLog() {
  canLogPrint = !canLogPrint
}
```

```css
#log {
  /*resize: none;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id='log' rows=25 cols=60 autofocus readonly></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="pauseLog()">PAUSE</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `for in` loop, wich [iterates in the object properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), in that case it is a list, so the object is like `{0:'3', 1: '4', 2:'5' ... }` and you're always printing the key instead of the value.

To fix that you can just use `logContents[s]` in your `for in` loop, or use `for of` loop.

Here's your code working.

```js
var logWidth = 60
var logHeight = 5
document.getElementById('log').setAttribute("rows", logHeight)
document.getElementById('log').setAttribute("cols", logWidth)


var canLogPrint = true
var txt = document.getElementById('log')
var x = 0
var logContents = []

setInterval(function() {
  if (canLogPrint) {
    updateLog(x.toString())
    x += 1
  }
}, 1000)

function updateLog(message) {
  logContents.push(message)
  if (logContents.length > logHeight) {
    logContents.shift()
  }
  txt.value = ''
  for (s of logContents) {
    txt.value += s + '\n'
  }
}

function pauseLog() {
  canLogPrint = !canLogPrint
}
```

```css
#log {
  /*resize: none;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id='log' rows=25 cols=60 autofocus readonly></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="pauseLog()">PAUSE</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `for .. in`. `for .. in` is used to iterate the keys of an object. As arrays are also Objects it will iterate the keys what means

```
   key value
    0    5
    1    6
    2    7
    3    8
    4    9
```

Now when the values changes the keys will be the same, that is the reason why your output still will be `0 1 2 3 4.`

You can use forEach here as in the example below.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #log {
                /*resize: none;*/
                overflow: hidden;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id='log' rows=25 cols=60 autofocus readonly></textarea>
        <br>
        <button onclick="pauseLog()">PAUSE</button>
        <script>
            var logWidth = 60
            var logHeight = 5
            document.getElementById('log').setAttribute("rows", logHeight)
            document.getElementById('log').setAttribute("cols", logWidth)


            var canLogPrint = true
            var txt = document.getElementById('log')
            var x = 0
            var logContents = []

            setInterval(function(){
                if (canLogPrint) {
                    updateLog(x.toString())
                    x += 1
                }
            },1000)

            function updateLog(message) {
                logContents.push(message)
                if (logContents.length > logHeight) {
                       logContents.shift();
                }
                txt.value = ''
                logContents.forEach((x) => {
                    txt.value += x + '\n'
                })
                    
                
            }

            function pauseLog() {
                canLogPrint = !canLogPrint
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok yea that works, but why can't a for..in loop be used??

Comment: @JamesMclaughlin `for/in` is used to enumerate an object's properties/keys. If it's used on an Array, it will enumerate the Array properties as well as the array indexes. `forEach` is specifically designed to enumerate only the indexes of an array.